# How to sort in ascending order 20 variables, in pine-script, TradingView?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, tradingview-api

How to dynamically sort, in ascending order 20 variables, in pine-script TradingView?

Comment: Step 1: [Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the variables into an array then use the array.sort function with order.ascending to automatically sort them as they enter the array.